# Passing parameter to Java Method then using that parameter in SQL Query Statement

Tags: java, sql

So the idea is that i can send an amount of bedrooms(int) as a parameter to a Java method which will use that int parameter in an SQL statement that returns all houses in the database with X amount of bedrooms.

```
public void displayProperty(int bedrooms) throws SQLException{

ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery("select * from PropertySale where bedroomsAmount = 'bedrooms' ;");
```

How exactly do i pass that parameter straight through to the statement?

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery("select * from PropertySale where bedroomsAmount =" + bedrooms + ";");
```